# Getting null item in select template of DataTemplateSelector

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding

I am trying to use ContentTemplateSelector of ContentControl to load the DataTemplate for it in code behind.

For the first time alone, getting null in the argument item of SelectTemplate.

Here is my code snippet.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.DataContext = new OrderInfoRepositiory();

    ContentControl c1 = new ContentControl();
    c1.ContentTemplateSelector = new EditTemplateSelector();
    c1.SetBinding(ContentControl.ContentProperty, new Binding());

    this.AddChild(c1);
}

public class CellTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {               

        return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
    }              
}
```

let me have a reason behind that.

Thanks.

Comment: Try to call `this.AddChild(c1)` before you set the binding. Then the DataContext would already be inherited.

Comment: @Clemens thank you for your answer. its working. i have another question. if DataContext is not set the problem, then the select template can be restricted before calling.

Answer (score 0):

To understand the reason behind the behavior that you describe we have to analyze your code.

The `ContentControl` c1 does not belong to the visual tree until you call the AddChild method, so there is no need to "disturb" its `ContentTemplateSelector`.
Instead when you add c1 to the Window, its ContentTemplateSelector will decide which template the control should apply.

Addind c1 to the Window means that you are changing its DataContext too. So the control asks its ContentTemplateSelector for a new DataTemplate.
When it happens the `SelectTemplate` method is called, but its parameter "item" is null, since the binding (you created it with this line: c1.SetBinding(ContentControl.ContentProperty, new Binding());) is not aware the source (I mean the DataContext) is changed yet.

After the DataContext changed event is processed, the binding begins to work and modifies the c1's ContentProperty. So now the the SelectTemplate method is called and this time the item parameter is not null.

If you do not like this behavior, just either declare your `ContentControl` in the XAML or add it to the window immedialty after you create it:

```
ContentControl c1 = new ContentControl();
this.AddChild(c1);

c1.ContentTemplateSelector = new TemplateSelector();
c1.SetBinding(ContentControl.ContentProperty, new Binding());
```

I hope it can help you.